# Do we still want the Answer Sandbox?

Tags: discussion, answers, sandbox

The [Answer Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/656/sandbox-for-proposed-answers) was created late December 2014 (see the [post](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/647/2685) about creating it for detail). Since then, it has generated:

- 3 votes (+3/-0)
- 1 favorite
- 2 comments
- **0 posts**.

In other words, it's not getting used.

Do we still want to keep this sandbox or can it be integrated? Is there any need for it at all? While those questions are largely a reiteration of the questions in the [original post](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/647/2685), I think it's worth a review given the low activity.

Comment: I would go against my earlier attitude and say "no" because it's no being used, but "yes" because there's no harm in keeping it. Is there?

Comment: "Integrated" into what, exactly?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit into the question sandbox

Comment: @ArtOfCode - I definitely wouldn't integrate it into the Q sandbox, because we have a lot of new users we direct to it and it could get confusing.  But, I agree the A sandbox is not really at this junction.  I'll note for reference, there were four answers, all subsequently deleted by their owner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ill still stick with my initial response to "Do we want an answer sandbox?" and say that I find it more important to have a question sandbox as **the implications of a bad or at least under-developed question have far more impact than a poor answer.**

Questions that need work can waste a lot of peoples' time.  Some of my early questions when beta opened were modified so many times that the original answers to the question didn't even makes sense anymore.

This is the primary reason I support the question sandbox, and you simply don't have the same issues with answers.

I'd vote we get rid of it for now and re-evaluate in a few months or a year to see if it is something we have a need for down the road.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect an answer sandbox is a little too far off the beaten path to get attention when it's needed.  If you're drafting an answer, it's probably because people's attention is on the *question* (and its other answers).  What prompts somebody to then go look at the sandbox for answers in progress?

On the other hand, somebody coming to the answer sandbox needs to do some work before he can really look at a post there -- you've got to at least go read the question and maybe the other answers, and then come back and read the proposed answer, and then provide feedback.

It seems like people are comfortable just posting their answers -- which is great; that's what we *want* people to do!  If somebody wants help on an answer before posting, then I'd suggest coming to chat, where there tend to be people around (or will be within hours) and where you can have more active engagement.  That seems better than posting a meta answer that might go unnoticed for much longer and then have slower conversation in comments.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: More to the point, what do we do with it? We could delete or we could just leave it

Comment: @ArtOfCode don't know; let's see what others have to say.

Answer (score -8):

Honestly this sound like censorship, there are tons of methods to deal with bad answers already.

Here in my country, we lived in a military ditactorship. And one of the undemocratic things that the military have done is the previous censorship.

This sounds suspiciously like previous censorship, ie, your answer must be first aproved here. What are you afraid of ? Why all that red tape ?

Comment: Uhhh... What? You realise that (a) this post is now over two years old, and (b) the only post in that sandbox is yours from yesterday, which combined with this is just a complaint that you're being censored because your answer was deleted.