# Should we have a community-wiki list of graduated answers from the Answer Sandbox?

Tags: discussion, answers, sandbox

The title says it all: For the [Answer Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/sandbox-for-proposed-answers), there's no list of graduated answers (linked directly to the answers, not the questions.) While the [Question Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) has a list of graduated answers, the Answer Sandbox answers can only be seen by higher-rep users. So should we post a community wiki answer and update it with previous answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No, there is no demand for it

There are currently 5 deleted posts, one of which was about undeleting an answer on Main. And the whole thread is 4.5 years old. There is on average about one draft per *year* in the answer Sandbox. There were discussions about [abandoning the answer Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/do-we-still-want-the-answer-sandbox) because nobody uses it. It simply isn't worth it to keep the answer Sandbox in check because there is basically no activity. I think it can just sit around and if someone comes across it and wants to safe a draft there or get some feedback they can use it, but as long as the amount of posts in the answer sandbox doesn't ramp up a lot we should just leave everything as it is.